# Is there any option to add mapped columns in DTO in jhipster filtering?

Tags: java, jpa, jhipster, dto

I added `"service": "serviceClass"` for generate filtering code in entity.json.

here are my entity.json:

```
 {
"name": "ExamScore",
"fields": [
    {
        "fieldName": "userId",
        "fieldType": "Long"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "score",
        "fieldType": "Float",
        "fieldValidateRules": [
            "required"
        ]
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "accept",
        "fieldType": "Boolean"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "insertDate",
        "fieldType": "String",
        "fieldValidateRules": [
            "required",
            "maxlength"
        ],
        "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 10
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "updateDate",
        "fieldType": "String",
        "fieldValidateRules": [
            "maxlength"
        ],
        "fieldValidateRulesMaxlength": 10
    }
],
"relationships": [
    {
        "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
        "otherEntityName": "exam",
        "otherEntityRelationshipName": "examScore",
        "relationshipValidateRules": "required",
        "relationshipName": "exam",
        "otherEntityField": "id"
    },
    {
        "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
        "otherEntityName": "executiveCourseScoreCeiling",
        "otherEntityRelationshipName": "examScore",
        "relationshipValidateRules": "required",
        "relationshipName": "executiveCourseScoreCeiling",
        "otherEntityField": "id"
    }
],
"changelogDate": "20200105110053",
"entityTableName": "exam_score",
"dto": "mapstruct",
"pagination": "no",
"service": "serviceClass",
"jpaMetamodelFiltering": true,
"fluentMethods": true,
"readOnly": false,
"clientRootFolder": "profile",
"applications": "*",
"microserviceName": "profile"
```

}

related codes created successfully and I can use filtering with fields.

Also, I added some fields in examScoreDTO.java which are mapped in examScoreMapper.java.

How can I use my mapped fields as well as my entity in the criteria object?

********  More explain

For Instance, ExamScore has a relation with the exam entity. I mapped the "date" field from the exam into examScoreDTO. Now, filtering is not working for the "date" field that is mapped from the exam entity

**********  update

examScoreMapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {ExamMapper.class, ExecutiveCourseScoreCeilingMapper.class})
```

public interface ExamScoreMapper extends EntityMapper<ExamScoreDTO, ExamScore> {

```
@Mapping(source = "exam.id", target = "examId")
@Mapping(source = "exam.finalScore", target = "examFinalScore")
@Mapping(source = "exam.absence", target = "examAbsence")
@Mapping(source = "exam.accept", target = "examAccept")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.id", target = "executiveCourseId")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.examDate", target = "examDate")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.startDate", target = "startDate")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.endDate", target = "endDate")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.course.name", target = "courseName")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.course.code", target = "courseCode")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.course.schoolGroup.id", target = "schoolGroupId")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.course.schoolGroup.basicInformation.name", target = "schoolGroupName")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.schoolTeacher.teacher.firstName", target = "teacherFirstName")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.schoolTeacher.teacher.lastName", target = "teacherLastName")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.schoolStudent.student.firstName", target = "studentFirstName")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.schoolStudent.student.lastName", target = "studentLastName")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.schoolStudent.mobileNumber", target = "mobileNumber")
@Mapping(source = "exam.registeration.schoolStudent.school.id", target = "schoolId")
@Mapping(source = "executiveCourseScoreCeiling.type.name", target = "examItem")
@Mapping(source = "executiveCourseScoreCeiling.type.id", target = "examItemId")
@Mapping(source = "executiveCourseScoreCeiling.id", target = "executiveCourseScoreCeilingId")
ExamScoreDTO toDto(ExamScore examScore);

@Mapping(source = "examId", target = "exam")
@Mapping(source = "examFinalScore", target = "exam.finalScore")
@Mapping(source = "examAbsence", target = "exam.absence")
@Mapping(source = "examAccept", target = "exam.accept")
@Mapping(source = "executiveCourseId", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.id")
@Mapping(source = "examDate", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.examDate")
@Mapping(source = "startDate", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.startDate")
@Mapping(source = "endDate", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.endDate")
@Mapping(source = "courseName", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.course.name")
@Mapping(source = "courseCode", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.course.code")
@Mapping(source = "schoolGroupId", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.course.schoolGroup.id")
@Mapping(source = "schoolGroupName", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.course.schoolGroup.basicInformation.name")
@Mapping(source = "teacherFirstName", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.schoolTeacher.teacher.firstName")
@Mapping(source = "teacherLastName", target = "exam.registeration.executiveCourse.schoolTeacher.teacher.lastName")
@Mapping(source = "studentFirstName", target = "exam.registeration.schoolStudent.student.firstName")
@Mapping(source = "studentLastName", target = "exam.registeration.schoolStudent.student.lastName")
@Mapping(source = "mobileNumber", target = "exam.registeration.schoolStudent.mobileNumber")
@Mapping(source = "schoolId", target = "exam.registeration.schoolStudent.school.id")
@Mapping(source = "examItem", target = "executiveCourseScoreCeiling.type.name")
@Mapping(source = "examItemId", target = "executiveCourseScoreCeiling.type.id")
@Mapping(source = "executiveCourseScoreCeilingId", target = "executiveCourseScoreCeiling")
ExamScore toEntity(ExamScoreDTO examScoreDTO);

default ExamScore fromId(Long id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ExamScore examScore = new ExamScore();
    examScore.setId(id);
    return examScore;
}
```

ExamScoreDTO:

```
public class ExamScoreDTO implements Serializable {

private Long id;

private Long userId;

@NotNull
private Float score;

private Boolean accept;

//    @NotNull
@Size(max = 10)
private String insertDate;

@Size(max = 10)
private String updateDate;


private Long examId;

private Long executiveCourseScoreCeilingId;
private Long examFinalScore;
private Long schoolGroupId;
private Long schoolId;
private Long executiveCourseId;
private Long examItemId;
private Boolean examAbsence;
private Boolean examAccept;
private String startDate;
private String endDate;
private String courseName;
private String courseCode;
private String schoolGroupName;
private String teacherFirstName;
private String teacherLastName;
private String studentFirstName;
private String studentLastName;
private String mobileNumber;
private String examItem;
private String examDate;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public Float getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(Float score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public Boolean isAccept() {
    return getAccept();
}

public void setAccept(Boolean accept) {
    this.accept = accept;
}

public String getInsertDate() {
    return insertDate;
}

public void setInsertDate(String insertDate) {
    this.insertDate = insertDate;
}

public String getUpdateDate() {
    return updateDate;
}

public void setUpdateDate(String updateDate) {
    this.updateDate = updateDate;
}

public Long getExamId() {
    return examId;
}

public void setExamId(Long examId) {
    this.examId = examId;
}

public Long getExecutiveCourseScoreCeilingId() {
    return executiveCourseScoreCeilingId;
}

public void setExecutiveCourseScoreCeilingId(Long executiveCourseScoreCeilingId) {
    this.executiveCourseScoreCeilingId = executiveCourseScoreCeilingId;
}

public Boolean getAccept() {
    return accept;
}

public Long getExamFinalScore() {
    return examFinalScore;
}

public void setExamFinalScore(Long examFinalScore) {
    this.examFinalScore = examFinalScore;
}

public Long getSchoolGroupId() {
    return schoolGroupId;
}

public void setSchoolGroupId(Long schoolGroupId) {
    this.schoolGroupId = schoolGroupId;
}

public Long getSchoolId() {
    return schoolId;
}

public void setSchoolId(Long schoolId) {
    this.schoolId = schoolId;
}

public Boolean getExamAbsence() {
    return examAbsence;
}

public void setExamAbsence(Boolean examAbsence) {
    this.examAbsence = examAbsence;
}

public Boolean getExamAccept() {
    return examAccept;
}

public void setExamAccept(Boolean examAccept) {
    this.examAccept = examAccept;
}

public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public String getCourseCode() {
    return courseCode;
}

public void setCourseCode(String courseCode) {
    this.courseCode = courseCode;
}

public String getSchoolGroupName() {
    return schoolGroupName;
}

public void setSchoolGroupName(String schoolGroupName) {
    this.schoolGroupName = schoolGroupName;
}

public String getTeacherFirstName() {
    return teacherFirstName;
}

public void setTeacherFirstName(String teacherFirstName) {
    this.teacherFirstName = teacherFirstName;
}

public String getTeacherLastName() {
    return teacherLastName;
}

public void setTeacherLastName(String teacherLastName) {
    this.teacherLastName = teacherLastName;
}

public String getStudentFirstName() {
    return studentFirstName;
}

public void setStudentFirstName(String studentFirstName) {
    this.studentFirstName = studentFirstName;
}

public String getStudentLastName() {
    return studentLastName;
}

public void setStudentLastName(String studentLastName) {
    this.studentLastName = studentLastName;
}

public String getMobileNumber() {
    return mobileNumber;
}

public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
}

public String getExamItem() {
    return examItem;
}

public void setExamItem(String examItem) {
    this.examItem = examItem;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    ExamScoreDTO examScoreDTO = (ExamScoreDTO) o;
    if (examScoreDTO.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(getId(), examScoreDTO.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ExamScoreDTO{" +
        "id=" + getId() +
        ", userId=" + getUserId() +
        ", score=" + getScore() +
        ", accept='" + isAccept() + "'" +
        ", insertDate='" + getInsertDate() + "'" +
        ", updateDate='" + getUpdateDate() + "'" +
        ", exam=" + getExamId() +
        ", executiveCourseScoreCeiling=" + getExecutiveCourseScoreCeilingId() +
        ", examFinalScore=" + getExamFinalScore() +
        ", examAbsence=" + getExamAbsence() +
        ", examAccept=" + getExamAccept()+
        ", startDate=" + getStartDate()+
        ", endDate=" + getEndDate()+
        ", courseName=" + getCourseName()+
        ", courseCode=" + getCourseCode()+
        ", schoolGroupId=" + getSchoolGroupId()+
        ", schoolGroupName=" + getSchoolGroupName()+
        ", teacherFirstName=" + getTeacherFirstName()+
        ", teacherLastName=" + getTeacherLastName()+
        ", studentFirstName=" + getStudentFirstName()+
        ", studentLastName=" + getStudentLastName()+
        ", mobileNumber=" + getMobileNumber()+
        ", schoolId=" + getSchoolId()+
        ", examItem=" + getExamItem()+
        ", executiveCourseId=" + getExecutiveCourseId()+
        ", examItemId=" + getExamItemId()+
        ", examDate=" + getExamDate()+
        "}";
}

public Long getExecutiveCourseId() {
    return executiveCourseId;
}

public void setExecutiveCourseId(Long executiveCourseId) {
    this.executiveCourseId = executiveCourseId;
}

public Long getExamItemId() {
    return examItemId;
}

public void setExamItemId(Long examItemId) {
    this.examItemId = examItemId;
}

public String getExamDate() {
    return examDate;
}

public void setExamDate(String examDate) {
    this.examDate = examDate;
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The JPA static metamodel generator only introspects the Entity not the DTO so all fields you added to the Entity are taken into account https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works with the entity very well. But I have some fields which I mapped in the mapper added to dto. The filtering is not working on those fields. I think the mapper is provided to query from relations.

Comment: You mean you want to filter on a field from a related entity? Your question is still not clear, consider showing some code. From what I understand you might be willing to do too much from generator and due to this your DTOs could be too similar to your entities without any real benefit. Have you considered writing your code manually to replace DTO mapping using MapStruct by JPA/Hibernate projections? And also writing manually your criteria?

Comment: Updated my question with additional source code. I'm willing to filter studentFirstName which is mapped in ExamScoreMapper and added to ExamScoreDTO.

Comment: Thanks, so I thjink my suggestions above apply well to your use case: drop mapstruct , use JPA projections and code manually your criteria builder

Comment: While dropping mapstruct, you can still benefit  from the generated classes under `target` but consider as a starting point that you will evolve manually